# Object is not a member of package error when sharing modules across multiple SBT project

Tags: scala, sbt

I have an sbt module with a `fooObject` defined in `io.myapp.foo` package. That is, the object can be accessed via `io.myapp.foo.fooObject`

I then publish this to my local Ivy repository via `sbt publishLocal`

In another Sbt project, I included this *foo object module*.

Then I try to use the `fooObject` in another class which is in the package `io.myapp.bar.barObject`. Even though my IDE can access `io.myapp.foo.fooObject` because I get autocomplete and I don't get a syntax error, but when I try to compile I get the error:

`Error:(19, 46) object foo is not a member of package io.myapp
    val schemaContent: String = fooObject.someValue`

Not sure why `foo` is being referred to as an object when it is just a path in the package name.

I have no idea why I am getting this compilation error. Any ideas?

**Edit: If I do SBT compile, it compiles, but when I run the tests, I get the said compilation error. Which makes it stranger**

**Edit2: Seems this is a case of Intellij tripping over itself. When I run the test from sbt, all passes. I get the compilation error only when I run test from Intellij**

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this ending up being a case of too many things going wrong at the same time...which made it harder to figure out why I was getting this unexpected behavior...

So I had a previous version of the module already publish to my local ivy, then I added the object to be shared and tried published again, but failed and I did not pay attention to the logs which mentioned that the publishing was not successful since it cannot overwrite the existing published artifacts.

Also in the other project where the compilation error was happening, I was running compile from the console, without reloading dependencies.

So making sure to delete before republish and making sure I reloaded dependencies solved my issue.

Hopefully, this helps someone else.

**Edit**
It so happened that I was still getting the compilation error when I run the test from Intellij. So I had to re-import the project again..that is from `File -> project structure -> module -> (delete and then readd)` After this, I can now run the test from intellij.

Talking about multiple things not working/going wrong at the same time! perfect recipe for confusion!